# How to exit a while cicle when user input a specific string, in JES, python 2.7

Tags: python, jython-2.7

in python, i want to  exit a while cicle, when, during the cicle, i'll input a specific string.

```
`while list!=[] or reply!="yes": 
 # @param list: list; list which contains strings of questions
     time.sleep(0.9)
     question=random.choice(list)
     print question
     print " "
     time.sleep(0.5)
     reply=raw_input("reply please: ")
     list.remove(question)
```

The problem it's: also if i reply "yes" to answer the while cicle continues, and print me the next question. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for the `break` statement:

```
if reply=='yes':
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the while condition to have `and` instead of `or`. With `or`, the loop continues while there are more items in the list.

You will also need to initialise `reply` to anything other than "yes" for the code to enter the while loop.